# MFC programming: error while compiling: error in code of a thread

Tags: c++, mfc, static-methods

I am getting errors in following code.

```
DWORD WINAPI CMbPoll::testThread(LPVOID lpVoid)
{
    DWORD dwWaitResult; 

    while(1)
    {
        dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(ghSemaphore, INFINITE/*0L*/);

        if (connectionSuccessful == 1)
        {
            staticConnectionStatus.ShowWindow(FALSE);
        }
        else
        {
            staticConnectionStatus.ShowWindow(TRUE);
        }

        MessageBoxW(L"hi");
        switch (dwWaitResult)
        {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                Read_One_t(pollSlaveId[0], pollAddress[0], 0);
                temporaryCount++;
                break;
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT: 
                temporaryCount++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Errors are:
I.
at `staticConnectionStatus.ShowWindow(FALSE);`
error C2228: left of '.ShowWindow' must have class/struct/union

II.
at `MessageBoxW(L"hi");`
error C2352: 'CWnd::MessageBoxW' : illegal call of non-static member function

I am not able to understand why these errors are appearing.

My declaration for `testThread` is:

```
static DWORD WINAPI testThread(LPVOID lpVoid);
```

`staticConnectionStatus` is a member variable for static text label on a form in MFC.

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_STATIC_CONFIG6, staticConnectionStatus);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because testThread is static. A static method cannot access instance variables of a class.

The solution (this has come up a lot recently) is to make testThread non-static, and use a call back function to start the thread and call `CMbPoll::testThread`, using the `this` pointer passed to `CreateThread`.

```
DWORD WINAPI thread_starter(LPVOID lpVoid)
{
    return ((CMbPoll*)lpVoid)->testThread();
}

CreateThread(..., thread_starter, this, ...);
```

I'm assuming that you start the thread from code in a `CMbPoll` method, if not then replace `this` with the address of your `CMbPoll` object.

Comment: Thank you very much for the precise answer.